# java stored procedure cause ORA-00911: invalid character

Tags: java, sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I'm try to call stored procedure in the following class which cause  "ORA-00911: invalid character" but I couldn't find where is the invalid character, all things seem fine to me as I followed stored procedure example.

```
public Info inquireData(String str)
         {
    Info result = new QuotaInfo();
    Connection con = null;
    CallableStatement callableStatement = null;
    try {
        con = (Connection) getEntityManager().unwrap(Connection.class);
        callableStatement = con.prepareCall("{ call WEB_DATA_INQUIRY(?,?,?,?,?,?) }");

        result = new Info();

        callableStatement.setString(1, str);
        callableStatement.registerOutParameter(2, Types.NUMERIC);
        callableStatement.registerOutParameter(3, Types.NUMERIC);
        callableStatement.registerOutParameter(4, Types.DATE);
        callableStatement.registerOutParameter(5, Types.NUMERIC);
        callableStatement.registerOutParameter(6, Types.VARCHAR);

        callableStatement.execute();


        result.setTotalNumber(callableStatement.getInt(2));
        result.setConsumedNumber(callableStatement.getInt(3));
        Date expiryDate = callableStatement.getDate(4);
        if (expiryDate != null) {
            result.setExpiryDate(new java.util.Date(expiryDate.getTime()));
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new DBException(e);
    }

    return result;

}
```

when I ran the program the exception appear as following:

```
com.walsa.web.dalayer.exception.DBException: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException:    ORA-00911: invalid character
 ORA-06512: at "WALSA.WEB_DATA_INQUIRY", line 12
 ORA-06512: at line 1
```

Comment: You have some `Dynamic SQL` inside your proc, and that is causing this. The stack trace says the same.(Line 12). The `Exceptions` like this should be caught inside the procedure, and the appropriate message should be returned to the caller.(`JDBC`)

Comment: so you mean that this piece of code is totally correct ?

Comment: Yes, your callable statement was successful, and only the proc threw an SQL Exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while we discover that java code connected correctly to that stored procedure. and the problem was inside the stored procedure itself.